# Passing optional arguments as list

Tags: python

When I have a function, I can pass the arguments as a list:

```py
def foo(a, b, c):
    print(a + b + c)

foo(*[1, 2, 3])  # 6
```

But what if I have optional arguments and only want to pass `a` and `c`, for example? I want to pass them as a list, if possible.

```py
def foo(a, b=0, c=0):
    print(a + b + c)

foo(*[?])  # 6
```

Comment: In short: you can't. `foo(**{'a': 1, 'c': 3})` would work, or rewriting the way defaults are handled.

Comment: A list doesn't seem suitable for that. If you specifically want to pass `a` and `c` use a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't.

By using list unpacking, you fill in positional arguments as they go in order.

```py
foo(*[1,2])
# works like
foo(1, 2)
```

To have certain values fill in certain named spots, you'd need to use keyword arguments, so dict unpacking

```py
foo(**{"a": 1, "c": 2})
# works like
foo(a=1, c=2)
```

If for some reason you

- cannot change the order of params in the function
- have your stuff as a list
- but you know the order in which to put those list elements (e.g. always a and c)...

...you could make a dict from your list and the order:

```py
foo(**dict(zip(['a', 'c'], [1, 2])))
```

Step-by-step explanation:

- zip makes two iterables into an iterable of pairs ~> `list(zip(['a', 'c'], [1, 2]))` gives `[('a', 1), ('c', 2)]`
- dict takes iterable of pairs and tries to make first element of the pair into a key and second as a value
- then we just unpack the prepared dictionary as keyword arguments

Notes:

If iterables are of different length, zip only works until the first is exhausted. The above will not raise an error for shorter or longer list. (It can only error out if we pass less stuff than we have params without default values)

But that also means if you use `zip(['a', 'c', 'b'], my_list)`, it will work for 1-elem, 2-elem, and 3-elem lists. (And for longer it will always take first 3 elements.)